# Need 2 jQuery instances to run at the same time on the same page

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote some jQuery to slide some text in, and then after a delay, slide it out again and slide the next one in. Here is the script:

```
var About = {
    init: function () {
        var text_spans = $('.headline-box a'),
            extracts = new Array(),
            delay = 5,
            current = 0;

        text_spans.each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                current = index;
            }
            extracts.push($(this));
        });

        var interval = setInterval(function () {

            target = (current < (extracts.length - 1)) ? current + 1 : 0;

            extracts[current].slideUp('slow');
            extracts[target].slideDown('slow');

            current = target;

        }, delay * 500);

    }
}

About.init();
```

It works, but I have two instances of `.headline-box` on the page, each with 3 links (`a`) in. Like this (simplified):

```
<div class="headline-box">
    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    <a href="#">Dolar Sit Amet</a>
    <a href="#">Aliquam imperdiet ornare</a>
</div>

<div class="headline-box">
    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    <a href="#">Dolar Sit Amet</a>
    <a href="#">Aliquam imperdiet ornare</a>
</div>
```

Everything works fine (they all slide in, and out) but here's the problem: one box will run through the sequence once, and stop, wait for the other box to run through it, and then the first will start again.

Does anyone have any idea why and how this could be fixed, so they both run simultaneously? Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class `About`, and create two instance:

```
function Abount() {
   //define class here
}

$(function() {
    $('.headline-box').each(function(n, elem) {
        new About(elem);
    });
})
```

Complete version: http://jsfiddle.net/vAbZ6/

Comment: whoops, @Timothy is faster than me.

Comment: Yours is more complete than mine, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the jquery each on each div.headline-box.

This should do it (or be pretty close).

```
$('div.headline-box').each(function(){
  var text_spans = $(this).children('a') ;
   extracts = new Array(),
        delay = 5,
        current = 0;

    text_spans.each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            current = index;
        }
        extracts.push($(this));
    });

    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        target = (current < (extracts.length - 1)) ? current + 1 : 0;

        extracts[current].slideUp('slow');
        extracts[target].slideDown('slow');

        current = target;

    }, delay * 500);
```

});

Comment: Hi Jim, your code makes it so that only 1 instance will run, and it goes very fast (slideIn, slideOut, constantly - I think this is because of the small delay). The other instance on the page just sits there. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: the each filter at the top should give you the 2 instances.  I suspect the interval logic is getting "overwritten" in the second div.headline-box.  I would have a look at query documentation to see if the animation can be done without the setInterval function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking all the anchor elements from every headline box and cycling through those in order.
From your updated answer, i gather you want the headline-boxes to independantly cycle through their child elements.

I have set up this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PqTD2/1/) with an example.

The trick is to make sure you keep separate track of the headline boxes you are cycling through.
The easiest way to do this, is to make an instance of a controller object for every header box.

In the example code, you can just call

```
var about_a = new About($("#box_a"));
var about_b = new About($("#box_b"));
```